# How exactly do Bake Margins work and can they be duplicated in post process?

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, texture-baking

When you Bake an image with Margins, it fills some area outside the edge of the UV island. For example, here is a section of a Normal map with a margin of 10 on the left, and 0 on the right. If you don't have Margins, you end up with visible seams when using the texture.
[image]

What process exactly is used to get this data outside the UV island? Is it like a post process smudge? I thought it was something like the Inpaint node in the compositor, but it does not give the same result. Is it possible to rebuild in the Compositor, or do in an external program?

Comment: I think it just stretches out the color on the edge of you UV seam. So if you have 10px margin, it would just drag the color for 10 pixels.